# Append only for first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table id="table" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>aaa</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>bbb</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>ccc</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<span id="append">append</span>   

$('#append').click(function(){
   $('table#table tr').append('<tr><td><table><tr><td>ddd</td></tr></table></tr>');
})
```

How can I use jQuery's append function on only the first element?  When I use append here, it appends all subtables.  I would only like to append the first subtable.  I tried with the `>` selector, but it is not working.  How can I achieve this effect?

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R3QXS/)

Comment: `$('table#table tr').first().append('stuff');`

Comment: To everyone saying 'append to the first `tr`' - you CANNOT have a `tr` element as a direct child of another `tr`! It has to be within a `table` or `tbody`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#table table tr:first").after('<tr><td><table><tr><td>ddd</td></tr></table></tr>');
```

Tested **[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R3QXS/11/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#append').click(function(){
    $('table#table tr').first().append('<tr><td><table><tr><td>ddd</td></tr></table></tr>');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `first()` method:

```
$('#append').click(function(){
    $('table#table tr').first().append('<tr><td><table><tr><td>ddd</td></tr></table></tr>');
})
```

Although that makes invalid HTML.. I think what you mean to append is:

```
<td><table><tr><td>ddd</td></tr></table></td>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3QXS/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the jQuery [first-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your requirements, the below should work. Note that I am appending to the first sub-table, as you cannot have a `tr` as a direct child of a `tr` (which is why you were ending up with another nested `table`.

```
$('#append').click(function(){
    $('#table table:first').append('<tr><td><table><tr><td>ddd</td></tr></table></tr>');
})
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/R3QXS/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('table#table tr:first-child')`